# django apache ImportError: No module named

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

So this is driving me crazy I have python3 and modwsgi and apache and a virtual host, that work great, as I have several other wsgi scripts that work fine on the server. I also have a django app that works great when I run the dev server.

I have checked that "ldd mod_wsgi.so" is linked correctly against python3.5

Whenever I try to access my site, I get an error and the apache log states:
ImportError: No module named 'protectionprofiles' 
protection profiles is mysite name the following is my virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName <my ip>
WSGIScriptAlias /certs /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearch/CavsCertSearch/certstrip.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /testcerts /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearchTest/CavsCertSearch/certstriptest.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /protectionprofiles /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py
        <Directory /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my site app is the protection profiles alias. I have no idea what the issue is I have tried following dozens of different apache tutorials and none of them seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

------ To add something else I tried --------
so I added the following 2 commands inside the virtual host

```
WSGIDaemonProcess protectionprofiles python-path=/var/www/protectionprofiles/
WSGIProcessGroup protectionprofiles
```

and no I get a different error

```
Error was: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
```

which is my backend, but the dev server works fine? Below is my database configuration

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'abcd1234',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'NAME': 'protectionprofile',
        }
    }
```

----Another error ----
Occasional I get

```
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

---- Another error!!--- Now when I update

```
WSGIDaemonProcess protectionprofiles python-path=/var/www/protectionprofiles/:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django
```

I get

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCookie'
```

---Another wierd thng is that when I have

```
WSGIProcessGroup protectionprofiles
```

enabled I dont get the error that it can't find the module "protectionprofiles" but when then non of my other wsgi scripts work!. They only work when thats no in there. Any explanation of that would be very helpful

Comment: Where is Django installed? Is it really installed in your system Python installation, or are you using a virtual environment? What version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for and what version are you wanting to use? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: django was installed with pip3 install django , I don't think I am using a virtual environment? everything was installed with apt or pip. Also all my wsgi scripts (the other two) that aren't django scripts work fine. Let me figure out the viersion of everything

Comment: dpkg -s libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 yields:  Version: 4.5.11-1. I am on ubuntu 1. and python is version 3.5.3

Comment: also I thing django is installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django

Comment: The ``populate()`` error is a side effect of the error occurring on trying to load the WSGI application. So that can be ignored at this point.

Comment: Do you have Python package ``psycopg2`` installed?

Comment: yes version 2.7.3.1 ... I just added the django install package to my path and now I no longer get the previous error but a new one! how many paths do you have to add for django to work?

Comment: You should need to add any extra paths for packages installed into the Python installation. That you are suggests your mod_wsgi isn't actually compiled for the Python installation you want. Find the ``mod_wsgi.so`` module and run ``ldd`` on it to see what it is linked to http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

Comment: among other things libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Comment: Thank you Graham for all the help I followed the link and I believe that it is linked against the same python version. One thing I noticed is that I am still running in embedded mode. Not sure how to force it to daemon mode?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to tell mod_wsgi where your project code is. For embedded mode this is done with `WSGIPythonPath` directive. You should preferably though use daemon mode, in which case you would use `python-path` option to `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive.

Comment: So I was trying to understand exactly what WSGIPythonPath does. do you list the directive for each location of you python code? putting WSGIPythonPath /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py still got the same error

Comment: You cannot use ``WSGIPythonPath`` inside of ``VirtualHost``, ``Location`` or ``Directory`` directive. This is why better to use daemon mode. Create separate daemon process group for each application and delegate each one to their own daemon process group. Either way, the argument to ``WSGIPythonPath`` or ``python-path`` option of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` is meant to be a directory, not a file like you are using.

Comment: Otherwise, add the directory to ``sys.path`` from inside of the WSGI script file.

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally figured out how to fix the issue but not sure exactly why. First off when I was mixing my own wsgi scipts and django I had to specify the daemon process only for the script alias that was django

```
WSGIScriptAlias /certs /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearch/CavsCertSearch/certstrip.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias /testcerts /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearchTest/CavsCertSearch/certstriptest.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias /debug /var/www/scripts/debug/debug.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py process-group=protectionprofiles
    WSGIDaemonProcess protectionprofiles python-path=/var/www/protectionprofiles/
WSGIProcessGroup protectionprofiles
```

Then in the app/settings.py in dev mode one backend worked but when ran in mod_wsgi I needed a different one:
settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'databse',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

In the development server "'django.db.backends.postgresql" worked fine but in release I had to specify the exact module type. I am not sure why but it works now!!

Comment: Sounds like you have a different Django version in production and development. The ``process-group`` option to ``WSGIScriptAlias`` shouldn't have made and difference as ``WSGIProcessGroup`` does the same thing.

Comment: hmm, I will have to look into that. I verified my django version when going through the documentation and the only way it was ever installed was pip3 install django....