# Django Python mod_wsgi: ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a Django-Python environment in Ubunt16.04u server but I get the Apache error: "ImportError: No module named 'django'"
I've installed Python 3.7, virtualenv (sudo pip install virtualenv), Django (pip install Django), mod_wsgi (sudo make install).

Which could be the reason of the issue?

**//Apache Error Log File**

```
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572605 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398] mod_wsgi (pid=60818): Target WSGI script '/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/curriculum/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572638 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398] mod_wsgi (pid=60818): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/curriculum/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572758 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572805 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398]   File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/curriculum/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572812 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Nov 21 17:45:07.572824 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 60818] [remote 192.168.224.1:56398] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

**//Apache Config File**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName cv-django.vmware
    ServerAlias www.cv-django.vmware
    DocumentRoot /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/cv
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/curriculum/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess cv-django.vmware processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/djang$
    WSGIProcessGroup cv-django.vmware

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/cv/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    Alias /static/ /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/cv/static/

     <Directory /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/cv/static>
      Require all granted
     </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerSignature On



    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**//wsgi.py**

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/curriculum/cv')

sys.path.append('/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.7/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'curriculum.settings')

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
except Exception:
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache ImportError: No module named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437882/django-apache-importerror-no-module-named)

Answer (score 3):

[SOLVED] The error was due to a wsgi python version mismatch. Apache was running a different version (Python 3.5).

I've followed the suggestions in these posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28118284/revisions

and

[Change mod_wsgi from python3.5 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096859/change-mod-wsgi-from-python3-5-to-3-6?rq=1)

Comment: Uninstalling libapache2 for Python2 and installing libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 for Python 3 did it for me. Nice one! :)